# CSS: Image Positioning Issue

Tags: css, drupal

I have a drupal 7 site for which I am adding a banner image as a content-type field. But then I'm using CSS to position it to absolute path with the following CSS rules.

```
    .field-name-field-banner-image {
        position:absolute;
        top:123px;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-490px;
    }
```

It works fine for a regular user, but when I login as an admin the position gets messed up because of Toolbar Overlay on top. What do I do to make it work for admin as well.
Here's the page http://azkaar.com/_mysites/muusa/

Comment: This is an issue with how Drupal handles certain elements depending on login state. What I suggest is that you find an alternative to this altogether instead of trying to make it work under different circumstances.

Comment: you can ask it in drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. as i look into this css your making field-name-field-banner-image center.

```
 .field-name-field-banner-image {
    position:absolute;
    top:123px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-490px;
}
```

try to put the specific width of the layout so it means if you have

```
 margin-left:-490px;
```

it should be like this

```
.field-name-field-banner-image {
    width:980px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:200;
    top:123px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-490px;
}
```

i addded z-index if you have issue on the overlaping.

But in drupal i think its an issue on the admin side. try to contact drupal support.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem you have is that you have specified `position: absolute`. Absolute position is in reference to the first parent that is not `static` (the default). So if you add `position: relative` to a parent, then the image will be in reference to that.

Because no parents have a relative property, the image is placed in reference to the page top. When you log in as an admin, an overlay is added that must push all the content down, thus screwing up the `top: 123px` value. Try adding

```
div#wrapper { position: relative; }
.field-name-field-banner-image { top: 113px; }
```

You will need to adjust the `top` value of the absolutely positioned div afterwards. It's hard to give an exact answer as I can't login under admin mode and see what the bar uses for its css and html.

Comment: Overall, this sounds reasonable, thanks.
  
If I position #wrapper as relative, the immediate parent-div to the banner will inherit it. But all this depends on if any other element in between these too is not positioned in a certain way.
 
What if I position the immediate parent-div as relative?
 
I will try different things based on your suggestion and update here.
 
Most probably I will remain the admin of this site, but I don't wanna do something that someone else working on the site can easily mess up. This positioning thing has always been tricky in CSS.

Comment: So it does not inherit, but the banner is positioned according to the closest parent that is set as relative. It worked best with #wrapper since the Toolbar Overlay stays above that. Thanks